# How do we rename the files after we have downloaded them using wget by reading their links from an external file?

Tags: bash, scripting, wget

I am trying to download some files using wget. I have stored all the links on a `.txt` file. When I read that file by the command `wget -i <filename>.txt`, the download starts but a notice is generated saying that the `file name is too long`. After this the download process is terminated.

How can I rename the files so that file name remains within acceptable range and the download continues.

Is there something like:- `wget -O <target filename> <URL>` for renaming files when downloaded from a `.txt` file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that this functionality exists in wget. You should probably loop through the file in a Perl or shell script, or something similar.

This example below is modified from an example at [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2131789). With minor modifications you could make it accommodate output file names to your needs. Now it limits file length to first 50 characters.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r link
  do
  output=`echo $link | cut -c 1-50`
  wget "$link" -O "$output"
done < ./links.txt
```

Comment: Modified the answer a little bit to be more specific to your question. Now it limits the file length to first 50 characters.

Answer (score 1):

## Using bash as a helper

```
for line in `cat input.txt`; do wget $line; done
```

You'll have to determine what you want the output names yourself, otherwise it will download them to whatever filename is in the url (e.g. blah.html) or index.html (if the URL ends in a slash).

## Dump all the files to one monolithic file

There is another option with `wget`, which is to use `--output-document=file`. It concatenates all the downloaded files into one file.